# Is their a way of getting a copy of my sons tributes and pictures from fb following his death

Tags: facebook, copy

Does anyone have any idea if this is can be done, or have had the same experience. it would be so sad to lose these memories so any ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for your loss... You could try PicknZip ...

http://www.picknzip.com/

This allows you to download files and videos from Facebook.

Comment: No problems at all Steve, I'm glad I was able to help.... Please feel free to mark which ever response has helped the most as the Answer. All the very best.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to memorialise an account with the following form.  Only people previously friends will be able to access the contents and it will allow them to post to the wall, but will also keep all previous information for posterity.

http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=305593649477238